# ASP.NET MVC dropdown with a default empty option

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, html-select

Is there a way to include a default empty option (or with text) if there is no selected value for a dropdownlist?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The below will prepend string.Empty to the SelectList (or IEnumerable) specified in the ViewData["Menu"] item.  The select will have id and name `MenuID`.

```
<%= Html.DropDownList( "MenuID",
                      (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Menu"],
                      string.Empty ) %>
```

Documentation: [DropDownList method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492883.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. The parameter name of optionLabel for the default option threw me off :)

Comment: Geez... me too I was starting to write my own helper method... rubbish name IMHO - sounds like it would output a <label> tag next to it.

Comment: Be aware that the ViewData-key must be different from the DropDown-Id (in this example "Menu" != "MenuID"). Else the framework overwrites the dropdown, ignoring the third parameter.

Comment: Awesome! Fixed my problem with select2.js too.

Answer (score 9):

**For Example:**

```
    Controller :

    private void InitScreenInfoCollate()
    {   
        IEnumerable<MstBrd> listbrd = ibrandRepository.GetItemsByUsercode("");
        ViewBag.Brands = new SelectList(listbrd, "brd_cod", "brd_mei", null);

    }

    View :
    @Html.DropDownList("Brands", null, string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Result :

[image: inline image]

Answer (score 1):

This easy solution worked for my mvc5 project:

**in view:**

```
@{
     Model.ModelItemsList.Add(new ModelItem{ });
     SelectList modelItemSelectList = new SelectList(Model.ModelItemsList, "ModelItemID", "ModelItemName");
}
```

Just add a new item to the `List<>` you want to display in your view.
In my case, I added a empty "ModelItem" to my `List<ModelItem> ModelItemList`. Since my ModelItemID is a Guid, I had to check for Guid.Empty in my controller method and do some code.
Thats all.

Answer (score -8):

The solution presented here worked very well for me: http://forums.asp.net/t/1142484.aspx/1

The basic idea is that you set the `AppendDataBoundItems` property of your `DropDownList` to `true` and then put an `asp:ListItem` in the `DropDownList` and that will become your default item with all the databound items coming after it.

Comment: `-1` This is for ASP.NET Web Forms, not MVC.